# Setup/configure MPIO in Windows Server 2016 with H810s and MD1200

Tags: windows-server-2016, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, dell-powervault, mpio

I'm having a difficult time finding info out on the google for this one

I have a Dell R710 with 2 PERC H810s in it running Windows Server 2016. I also have a MD1200 filled up with 3TB disks configured as a single RAID6 Virtual Disk. I've gotten the firmware of both H810's to the latest version on Dell's website: 21.3.5-0002

I have installed the Multipath I/O role/feature and I have checked the "Add support for SAS devices" under:
Server Manager -> Tools -> MPIO -> Discover MultiPaths

I have connected the SAS cables as follows:

```
MD1200 EMM A -> H810 (PCI Slot 3) Connector 0
MD1200 EMM B -> H810 (PCI Slot 4) Connector 0
```

When the R710 boots, I get a BIOS error for one of the H810's saying that there is no configuration, However once in Windows both H810s show a virtual drive in OpenManage Server Administrator. Disk Management shows two disks, one is online with a drive letter assigned and the other shows as offline.

When I run CyrstalDiskMark, I'm getting the same bandwidth results as with just one H810. What I'm attempting to get up and running is to use both H810s with MPIO to help increase bandwidth to the MD1200. Any help and pointers would be greatly appreciated.